# Format Excel Workbook With EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using `EPPLUS` with `ASP.NET` to extract a `DataTable` to Excel.  The actual extract portion works perfect, but I can't figure out how to format a column as a Percentage.  I tried using `#0\\.00%` but all that did was 0 and a percentage at the end.  So if my my original data was `.34` using `#0\\.00%` would format it to `0.34%` 

My desired out put / formatting I want is for `EPPLUS` to format the number `.34` to be `34.00%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try and use this `#0.00%`
A quick run down ... in custom formats, % means "add % and multiply by 100", while \% means "just add %"

Comment: Worked perfectly.  And thank you for letting me know about the custom formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom formats
you can try below code

worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00%";
worksheet.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex].Style.Numberformat.Value = Decimal.Parse(.34)